# Drawing a segment between two points on a logarithmic spiral in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw an algorithmic spiral on which I mark points from the list `numbers`, which indicate the distance from the beginning of the spiral (green points). Then I try to draw a segment between two selected points. Blue points belong to a set of points drawn by the `scatter` function, and black points are selected by using only their coordinates directly. My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   
a = 1.1
b = 0.1
th = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
x = a*np.exp(b*th)*np.cos(th)
y = a*np.exp(b*th)*np.sin(th)

diffs = np.sqrt(np.diff(x)**2+np.diff(y)**2)
length = diffs.sum()

numbers = [2,4,7,8,13,16,18,19,22,26,28,31,35,37,44,48,55,56,59,60,65]
p2 = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    cumlenth = np.cumsum(diffs)
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(cumlenth-numbers[i]))).astype(bool)
    c = np.argwhere(s)[0][0]
    p = [x[c]], [y[c]]
    p2.append(list(p))

ax.cla()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for j in range(len(p2)):   
    ax.scatter(p2[j][0],p2[j][1], color='green')

ax.scatter(p2[10][0],p2[10][1], color='blue')
ax.scatter(p2[20][0],p2[20][1], color='blue')

ax.plot(x, y)

plt.plot(p2[10], p2[20], color='k',marker='o')

plt.show()
```

Where I receive:

[image]

Why are the blue and black points not overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x[1,3], y[2,4]
```

With **plot**(x,y) --> **plot**(1,3,2,4) 
If you want drawing a segment between two points (x,y) with **plot** 
 You should update x and y:
x[1,2], y[3,4]

With your code, you can try with:

```
a1 = [p2[10][0],p2[20][0]]
a2 = [p2[10][1],p2[20][1]]
plt.plot(a1,a2,color='k',marker='o' )
```

Comment: oh, I used the wrong coordinate assignments;) thanks.